# Open docker daemon container to outside

Tags: docker

The docker daemon container is isolated from outside when we run it below,

```
$ docker run -d --name test_container ubuntu/ping \
/bin/sh -c "while true do echo hello world; sleep 1; done"

$ docker inspect test_container | grep IPAddress
[ip of test_container]

$ ping [ip of test_container]
[timeout]

$ ifconfig docker0 | grep "inet addr"
[ip of docker bridge]

$ ping [ip of docker bridge]
[ok]

$ docker exec -it test_container /bin/bash

# ping [ip of test_container]
[ok]

# ping [ip of docker bridge]
[timeout]
```

How to open the ip address of the docker daemon container inside out?

Answer (score 0):

By default docker daemon is running on a unix socket

You can enable to listen on tcp socket by doing :

> docker daemon -H tcp://validIpOnYourHost:port

By default port is 2375 if you do not provide some.

cf this page for more explanation : https://docs.docker.com/v1.11/engine/reference/commandline/daemon/

Be careful, if you expose docker throught TCP, this is not security enabled.

Answer (score 0):

Probably I replied to something else, after reading your question :

could you do a :

> docker network inspect bridge

and paste the json output.
I had similar issues when the attribute :

> "com.docker.network.bridge.enable_ip_masquerade"

was set to false

Comment: `enable_ip_masquerade` is set to `true`, but `host_binding_ipv4` is set to `0.0.0.0`.

Comment: For some reason the commnd line you provided generated an error in the shell : coule you maybe retry with **docker run --name test_container ubuntu/ping /bin/sh -c "while true; do echo hello world; sleep 10; done;**

Comment: I have the same output : `"Options": {
            "com.docker.network.bridge.default_bridge": "true",
            "com.docker.network.bridge.enable_icc": "true",
            "com.docker.network.bridge.enable_ip_masquerade": "true",
            "com.docker.network.bridge.host_binding_ipv4": "0.0.0.0",
            "com.docker.network.bridge.name": "docker0",
            "com.docker.network.driver.mtu": "1500"
        }`